# Calling getter / setter in javascript with variable

Tags: javascript

So I am currently working through some code academy problems and was thinking about the "recommended" solution from them. The code is as follows:

```
  ...

  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
    ...
    return this._courses['appetizers'];
  },

  generateRandomMeal() {
    const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    ...

    return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name}...`
  }
```

So they call the `getRandomDishFromCourse` with a string as an argument and then in the function I access the object through the bracket notation. How would I solve this with getters and setters instead? What is the best practice for this?

My idea for solving this is presented below, but does not work...

```
  get appetizers() {
    return this._courses._appetizers;
  },

  ...

  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
    let dish = courseName;
    return dish;
    ...
  },

  generateRandomMeal() {
    const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse(this.appetizers);
    ...

    return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name}...`
  }
```

Comment: Please create a working snippet demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Note that your `set` for `appetizers` accessors is incorrect: It doesn't set `appetizers`, it *adds* to `appetizers`. Just adding to the array isn't a use-case for a setter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the input, I have actually removed the setter since the question is valid only for the getter. My basic question is how do you "pass" a getter instead of passing a string that you access through bracket notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My basic question is how do you "pass" a getter instead of passing a string that you access through bracket notation?

You don't. But you can pass the array:

```
getRandomDishFromCourse(course) {
  let disk = course[Math.floor(course.length * Math.random())];
  return dish;
},

generateRandomMeal() {
  const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse(this.appetizers);
  // ...
}
```

...or a function that gets the appropriate array:

```
getRandomDishFromCourse(getCourse) {
  let course = getCourse();
  let disk = course[Math.floor(course.length * Math.random())];
  return dish;
},

generateRandomMeal() {
  const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse(() => this.appetizers);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks that makes sense!